# how can I set random color for text area?

Tags: javascript, textarea

Hi I want to make kind of type checker.
so when you put some text to input box, that text appear to the textarea.
I want to set random text color for textarea..
I used this code :

```
let letters = document.querySelector('#txt').innerHTML.split('');
let quote = document.querySelector('#author').innerHTML.split('');

// Converts integer to hex 
const colToHex = (c) => {
// Hack so colors are bright enough
let color = (c < 75) ? c + 75 : c
let hex = color.toString(16);
return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

// uses colToHex to concatenate
// a full 6 digit hex code
const rgbToHex = (r,g,b) => {
return "#" + colToHex(r) + colToHex(g) + colToHex(b);
}

// Returns three random 0-255 integers
const getRandomColor = () => {
return rgbToHex(
 Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
 Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
 Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
}

// This is the prototype function
// that changes the color of each
// letter by wrapping it in a span
// element.
Array.prototype.randomColor = function() {
let html = '';
this.map( (letter) => {
 let color = getRandomColor();
 html +=
   "<span style=\"color:" + color + "\">"
   + letter +
   "</span>";
}) 
return html;
};

// Set the text
document.querySelector('#txt').innerHTML = letters.randomColor();
document.querySelector('#author').innerHTML = quote.randomColor();
```

but it is not working...
Is there any solutions..?
regards.

Comment: So your code runs on page load. Not sure how you expect it to see text change when you have no event listeners.

Comment: Yeh your code seems fine, but I wouldn't recommend changing the Array prototype for that.

Comment: And if it is a `<textarea>` it does not have have innerHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement the color of each letter can't be displayed in textarea because you can't use html tags inside textarea but, can be displayed in div with `contenteditable="true"` property.

```js
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value
  let splitValue = inputValue.split("");
  splitValue.forEach((element)=>{
  let text = element;
  let result = text.fontcolor(getRandomColor());
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += result
})
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
.divTextArea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 175px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: max-content;
  max-height: max-content;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
<div class="divTextArea" contenteditable="true" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to change the color of the text you can give document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.color = getRandomColor();

Comment: thank you very much! but with this code ..I want to change the color of each letter every time I input a letter, but this changes the color of the entire text in the text area....

Comment: I have edited the code. You can check once

Comment: If you want to add the letter in div as soon as you enter any letter in input then in that case you have to use angular two-way binding. You can take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_model_two-way

Comment: @yeoleumyun  Please tick if you got the answer.